# Using React useRef Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been building Select Component of my own using button components in React. I am stuck on how to close the menu when the user clicks outside the menu. The code sandbox can be found here:

[image: Edit Select Component using buttons]

I am thinking of adding an event listener when the component is mounted, which would track whether the click was made inside of the menu or not. I am expecting to solve this using useRef Hook.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because it is from an external site but I wrote an article for something similar https://javascript.plainenglish.io/reactbits-clearable-input-with-autofocus-bad64462ab4?sk=19feebb489f6b1fea6f0c00d7507bca5, check the References part

Comment: Great article mate. But I couldn't exactly figure out on why was there a need for containerRef. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    {
      label: "Apple",
      value: "apple"
    },
    {
      label: "Ball",
      value: "ball"
    },
    {
      label: "Car",
      value: "car"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SelectComponent options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}

function SelectComponent(props) {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const [selectedVal, setSelectedVal] = useState("");
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      //Insert code here.
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, false)
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, false)
})

const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) setIsMenuOpen(false)
}

  const onSelectClick = () => {
    setIsMenuOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const onValueSelect = (e) => {
    const {
      target: { id }
    } = e;
    setSelectedVal(id);
    setIsMenuOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  const computeClass = isMenuOpen ? "close-icon" : "open-icon";

  return (
    <div {...{ref}}>
      <button
        className={`select-btn selected-val ${computeClass}`}
        onClick={onSelectClick}
      >
        {selectedVal}
      </button>
      {isMenuOpen &&
        props.options.map((item) => {
          return (
            <button
              key={item.value}
              id={item.label}
              value={item.value}
              className={"select-btn"}
              onClick={onValueSelect}
            >
              {item.label}
            </button>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Was able to resolve using this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way to handle the useRef in the component is shown below :-

**Here our target is to resize the input filed on submit button click.**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const UseRef = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleSize = ()=>{
    console.log("submit");
    inputRef.current.style.width="300px"
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        style={{ padding: "10px" }}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleSize} >submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UseRef;
```

**inputRef** is the instance of the useRef which I have passed in the specific DOM element which we are going to manipulate on click event of submit button.

**inputRef.current.style.width="300px"** this is the manipulation done with the DOM element which is passed in the function *handleSize()*

When onClcik event is invoked from submit button size of the button will be increased to 300px .

We can also get the same result by avoiding import of useState & by eleminating onChange & value props from the input filed.